# What is the best way to write readable code using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have some node.js promise code that looks something like this:

```
function myFunc(data) {
  Q(data).then(function(data) {
    return getPromise1(globalVar).then(function(res1a) {
      return getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2)).then(function(res2a) {
        return doStuff();
      }).then(function(res2b) {
        return getPromise3(data).then(function(res3a) {
          return getPromise4.then(function(res4a) {
            // more stuff
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

As you can see, this code is not very readable. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You probably don't need to nest it.  You can probably do `a().then(...).then(...).then(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the goals of promises besides separating data parameters from control flow parameters was actually to solve this issue of huge triangular blocks of code.

```
function myFunc(data) {
  Q(data).then(function(data) {
    return getPromise1(globalVar);
  }).then(function(res1a) {
    return getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2));
  }).then(function(res2a) {
    return doStuff();
  }).then(function(res2b) {
    return getPromise3(data);
  }).then(function(res3a) {
    return getPromise4;
  }).then(function(res4a) {
    // more stuff
  })
}
```

Now, the only reason you would ever need to nest a promise is if you need to use data returned from a promise in a function not immediately following it. See below:

```
doAsyncA().then(function(x) {
  doAsyncB().then(function(y) {
    doSyncUsingBothReturns(x, y);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t need all of the results at once, just stop treating promises like callbacks:

```
function myFunc(data) {
  Q(data).then(function(data) {
    return getPromise1(globalVar);
  }).then(function(res1a) {
    return getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2));
  }).then(function(res2a) {
    return doStuff();
  }).then(function(res2b) {
    return getPromise3(data);
  }).then(function(res3a) {
    return getPromise4;
  }).then(function(res4a) {
    // more stuff
  })
})
```

If you do, then you can try [coroutines](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) given generator function support (Q probably has something for that, but here’s a [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) way):

```
var myFunc = bluebird.coroutine(function* myFunc(data) {
  var res1a = yield getPromise1(globalVar);
  var res2a = yield getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2));
  var res2b = yield doStuff();
  var res3a = yield getPromise3(data);
  var res4a = yield getPromise4;

  // more stuff
})
```

or [synchronous inspection](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/synchronous-inspection.html):

```
function myFunc(data) {
  var res1a = getPromise1(globalVar);
  var res2a = res1a.then(function() {
    yield getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2));
  });
  var res2b = res2a.then(function() {
    // feel free to use res1a.value() here;
    // you know that it has to have been resolved
    doStuff();
  });

  // …

  return res4a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example it would help to use lambda expressions:

`Q(data)
.then(data => getPromise1(globalVar)
.then(re1a => getPromise2(JSON.parse(param2)`

and so on.
Without nesting and in this style, it looks much less like callback hell :)